# how to display Custom objects on x-axis in CPTScatterPlot graph

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot

I have implemented custom objects(coming from webservices) on y-axis starting at y orthogonal 40 at interval of 20 in y-axis and its working correct.
At present we are showing time interval of 1 day in x-axis. But now i want to display custom objects(i.e dates but there are chances of occurring 2 different time of same date) (coming from webservices)at interval of 20 as done in y-axis. 
I tried similar to y-axis but it didn’t work. All values are displaying in single position but not in interval of 20.
Sample server response is as shown below only for x-axis.
For example:-

```
{
      date : “2015-12-25 6:30:00”,
      date : “2015-12-30 14:00:00”,
      date : “2016-01-25 5:30:00”,
      date : “2016-01-25 7:00:00”,
      date : “2016-01-10 10:00:00”,
      date : “2016-01-10 12:30:00”,
      date : “2016-01-11 11:00:00”,
      date : “2016-01-12 16:30:00”
}
```

This is my code:

```
-(void)reloadData
{
    if ( !self.graph ) {
        CPTXYGraph *newGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.graph = newGraph;

        newGraph.paddingTop    = 0.0;
        newGraph.paddingBottom = 0.0;
        newGraph.paddingLeft   = 0.0;
        newGraph.paddingRight  = 0.0;


        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 2.0f;
        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 8.0f;
        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 30.0f;
        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 42.0f;


        //self.graph.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];

        self.graph.paddingTop = 2.0f;
        self.graph.paddingRight = 2.0f;
        self.graph.paddingBottom = 2.0f;
        self.graph.paddingLeft = 2.0f;



        CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:newGraph.bounds];
        dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Systolic";

        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
        dataSourceLinePlot.delegate   = self;

        CPTColor *areaColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:249.0/255.0 green:183.0/255.0 blue:183.0/255.0 alpha:.7];
        CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:areaColor];
        [dataSourceLinePlot setAreaFill:areaGradientFill];
        [dataSourceLinePlot setAreaBaseValue:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(60)]];//[NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)]];

        CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
        lineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
        CPTXYAxisSet axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet ) newGraph.axisSet;
        /*

         // 3 - Configure x-axis
         CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
         */

        // set the majorGridLinestyleProperty by this line as.
        CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        gridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor grayColor];
        gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

        gridLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
        gridLineStyle.patternPhase=0.0f;



        dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

        axisSet.yAxis.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
        //        axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;

        axisSet.xAxis.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
        // axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;

        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
        [newGraph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];



        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot2 = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:newGraph.bounds];
        dataSourceLinePlot2.identifier = @"Diastolic";

        dataSourceLinePlot2.dataSource = self;
        dataSourceLinePlot2.delegate   = self;

        CPTColor *areaColor1 = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:229.0/255.0 green:87.0/255.0 blue:87.0/255.0 alpha:.7];

        CPTFill *areaGradientFill1 = [CPTFill fillWithColor:areaColor1];
        [dataSourceLinePlot2 setAreaFill:areaGradientFill1];
        [dataSourceLinePlot2 setAreaBaseValue:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(60)]];

        CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle1 = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        CPTColor *aaplColor1 = [CPTColor redColor];
        lineStyle1.lineColor = aaplColor1;
        dataSourceLinePlot2.dataLineStyle = lineStyle1;

        dataSourceLinePlot2.dataSource = self;
        [newGraph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot2];
    }

    CPTXYGraph *theGraph = self.graph;
    self.graphHost.hostedGraph = theGraph;

    CPTXYPlotSpace plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace )theGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.delegate = self;


    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];

    NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24  60  60;
    NSTimeInterval xLow = 0.0f;

    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow)]
                                                    length:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay*5.0f)]];

    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@50.0 length:@(120)];

    // Axes
    CPTXYAxisSet axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet )theGraph.axisSet;


    NSDate refDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:31556926  10];
    // added for date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];
    // dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
    CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
    NSLog(@"Ref date: %@", refDate);
    timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;


    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength   = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay)];
    x.orthogonalPosition    = @60.0;
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;

    CPTXYAxis *y  = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.majorIntervalLength   = @20;
    y.majorTickLineStyle    = nil;
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    y.minorTickLineStyle    = nil;
    y.orthogonalPosition    = @60.0;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    [theGraph reloadData];
}
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:]` to convert the date strings received from the server into `NSDate` objects. It looks the graph is already set up to display the dates.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  we are getting graph but we are displaying date based on interval of a day difference(i.e 24hrs) in x-axis but as i already explained scenario of getting 2 values with same date having different time, how to handle this condition? please look on a response date for more clarity.

Comment: You can repeat x- or y-values on a scatter plot. If you want to drop the time component, convert the date to `NSDateComponents` with `
-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]`, clear the time components, and retrieve the new `date`.